# NoRM MongoDB : Build complex filters or add filters to existing queries

Tags: c#-4.0, mongodb, norm

How to build multicriterial queries in Norm driver adding extra filters to one existing base query? Thanks.

```
var coll= mongo.GetCollection<TaggedContents>();  
var coll2 = coll.AsQueryable().Where(x=> x.ID==ID && x.Name=="Name");  
var coll3 = coll2.AsQueryable().Where(x=> x.TagId==tagId && x.TagName=="TagName");
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a candidate for the LINQ Union operator, roughly the SQL equivalent of "AND" or "OR"